# FFMPEG video conversion to MP4 works everywhere except in iOS Safari/Chrome

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4

I use the following code to convert `.webm` videos to `.mp4` using the FFMPEG library:

```
ffmpeg -i video.webm -vcodec h264 -acodec aac -strict experimental video.mp4
```

This works flawless when playing the converted video in Windows (Chrome/Firefox), Mac (Safari/Chrome), Android (Chrome) but it does not work when watching through iOS (Safari/Chrome).

At first I thought it might be an `mp4` problem? But then I played without any problems in my iOS Safari this video https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4 which is also a `mp4`.

So this tells me that something is not quite right about the conversion.

What am I missing in the conversion?

Log from PuTTy: https://pastebin.com/VLSPL0nC

Comment: Show the complete log from your command.

Comment: @llogan added the log

Comment: Your `ffmpeg` is ancient. [Download](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) or [compile](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Centos) a new version. Then remove `-strict experimental` (that's only needed for really old builds), add `-movflags +faststart`, and try again. If it still fails add `-profile:v main`.

Comment: @llogan thank you, will do. I just tried with `-profile:v main -level 3.1` and it worked. And I just saw that `-strict experimental` was removed in 2015 or something!!

Comment: I doubt you need `-level`.

Comment: how to convert you 
third-party library or standalone library 
now browser support convent with library

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Your `ffmpeg` is ancient. [Download](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) or [compile](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Centos) a new version.
2. Remove `-strict experimental` (that's only needed for really old builds).
3. Add `-movflags +faststart` so it can begin playback faster.
4. Add `-vf format=yuv420p` for a compatible pixel format.
5. Output AAC audio (`-c:a aac`) instead of MP3 (`-c:a libmp3lame`).
6. If it still fails it may be due to the device not supporting High profile. Add `-profile:v main`. You don't need to add this if your device supports High profile.

Example:

```
ffmpeg -i input -c:v libx264 -profile:v main -vf format=yuv420p -c:a aac -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

- Refer to the specifications of your target device to determine the appropriate `-profile:v` (and possibly `-level`).
- See [FFmpeg Wiki: H.264](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264) for more info.

Comment: Hey, dou you happen to know how do I update my current FFMPEG version through shell? Is there any command, like `yum FFMPEG update`?

Comment: @Linesofcode If yum supplies ffmpeg then it would probably be outdated. If you download a build from my first link then you can move the ffmpeg executable file into `/usr/local/bin` (or `~/bin` if you don't have permission).  If you follow the second link and compile the instructions will do everything for you.

Comment: Hey @llogan can you check this question, please?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69662784/videos-created-with-ffmpeg-do-not-play-on-ios-safari

Answer (score 1):

Safari requires your web server to support HTTP range requests. So make sure it does!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the arguments provided by @llogan, I found that lowering the frame rate of my videos was the key to playback in browser on IOS. I had success after adding `fps=30` as a video filter.

Note: If there are multiple video filters, such as `format=yuv420p` then the filters need to be surrounded by quotes and separated by commas, like so:

`-vf "format=yuv420p, fps=30"`