# The mediaElement.play() method returns a promise that is rejected

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I can't play my video on mobile Browsers. When using Safari Remote Debugging, i get the following issue:

`Unhandled Promise Rejection: AbortError: The operation was aborted.`

I find this solution: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/06/play-request-was-interrupted

But i don't know, how can i use it in my code to fix the problem.

```html
<video muted id="video" class="absolute right-0 bottom-0 min-w-full min-h-full w-auto" controls>
    <source src="/path/to/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

```js
let video = document.getElementbyId('video');
let video_cta = document.getElementbyId('video_cta');

//this doesn't fix my problem
var videoPromise = video.play();

if (videoPromise != undefined) {
    videoPromise.then(function(_) {
      video.pause();
      video.currentTime = 0;
  });
}

//start video after click the button
video_cta.addEventListener('click' function() {
    video.play()
})
```

Comment: I was getting the same issue when running on the local debug environment. Have you tried publishing the code and testing on a PROD or Testing environment? As for me the issue goes away when publishing the code and testing directly on a domain. Looks like anything different to http://localhost will work.
That worked for me. Let us know if work for some of you as well.

Answer (score 5):

- First thing is that `autoplay` attribute is needed.

  > `<video src='...' controls muted`**autoplay**`></video>`
- When `videoPromise` is the reference to the video and call to the `.play()` method, it will work within a Promise.

  > `const videoPromise = document.querySelector('video').play();`
- Also there is a dependency in OP code `.getElementById()` was misspent:

  > `let video = document.getElement`**b**`yId('video');`
  >   `let video_cta = document.getElement`**b**`yId('video_cta');`
- The [Google article](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/06/play-request-was-interrupted#danger-zone) provided in OP also mentions that the `<source>` tag will not handle a `reject` properly:

  > **Use**
  >
  > `<video src='...'></video>`
  >
  > **Not**
  >
  > `<video>
  >   <source src='...'>
  >   </video>`
- This should stop the error message:

  > `Unhandled Promise Rejection: AbortError: The operation was aborted.`

**Demo 1** uses a `Promise` and method `.then()`. **Demo 2** uses `async/await`. The `async function` is wrapped in an IIFE ([**I**mmediately **I**nvoked **F**unction **E**xpression](https://medium.com/@vvkchandra/essential-javascript-mastering-immediately-invoked-function-expressions-67791338ddc6))

#### Demo 1

**Promise**

```js
let cta = document.querySelector('#cta');

const videoPromise = document.querySelector('video').play();

if (videoPromise != undefined) {
  videoPromise.then(_ => {
video.play();
  });
}

cta.addEventListener('click', function() {
  video.play();
});
```

```html
<video src="https://storage04.dropshots.com/photos6000/photos/1381926/20170326/005609.mp4" id="video" class="absolute right-0 bottom-0 min-w-full min-h-full w-auto" controls autoplay muted></video>
<button id='cta'>CTA</button>
```

#### Demo 2

**`async/await`**

```js
let cta = document.querySelector('#cta');

const video = document.querySelector('video');

(function() {
  playMedia();
})();

async function playMedia() {
  try {
    await video.play();
  } catch (err) {}
}

cta.addEventListener('click', function() {
  video.play();
});
```

```html
<video src="https://storage04.dropshots.com/photos6000/photos/1381926/20170326/005609.mp4" id="video" class="absolute right-0 bottom-0 min-w-full min-h-full w-auto" controls autoplay muted></video>
<button id='cta'>CTA</button>
```

Comment: thanks for answer, but i get now the following error on safari mobile: 
`Unhandled Promise Rejection: NotSupportedError: The operation is not supported.`

Comment: thanks for updating, but the Demo 2 doesn't work too. I get the error: `Unhandled Promise Rejection: NotAllowedError: The request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied permission.`

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem.
The video didn't play in Safari. But apparently, when I put different mp4 file in same place, the video played successfully.
I used ffmpeg tool with different settings to generate the video. See related answer [FFMPEG video conversion to MP4 works everywhere except in iOS Safari/Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54335106/ffmpeg-video-conversion-to-mp4-works-everywhere-except-in-ios-safari-chrome).

In short, make sure you tried some other video file.