# Videos created with FFMPEG do not play on IOS/Safari

Tags: video, ffmpeg, safari

I have a video file, and I wanted to do a few operations on the video file with ffmpeg, but I realized that after I input the video to ffmpeg, the output video doesn't work on IOS.

I noticed that this is the same when I don't give any settings to ffmpeg or some codecs.

Links to the videos:

[Original](https://filebin.net/0i0klaqpjqj4nlgw/test.mp4)

[Processed](https://filebin.net/0i0klaqpjqj4nlgw/f82bdc41-6365-4d50-923d-24941d73ad13.mp4)

Someone had a similar issue before, but the solution there is not working for me.

[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54335942/13772090)

Note: Here are the ffmpeg settings of the processed video:

```
ffmpeg -i path/to/file.mp4 path/to/out.mp4
```

Note2: I noticed the original video is 15mb and the processed video is 5mb. Obviously, the quality of the video is going away. How can I keep the quality the same?

Comment: The processed file works for me in iOS Safari. Because you omitted `-movflags +faststart` you have to wait for it to completely download before it plays.

Comment: I solved the problem and the source of the problem was not related to ffmpeg. I was uploading files to Google Cloud Storage and always tested from there. When uploading the file there, I was using the `gzip: true` setting. It wasn't working on IOS/Safari because of gzipping. Thanks for your attention and help!

Answer (score 0):

So I noticed this problem is not related with the FFMPEG.

While uploading something to the GCS, I was setting GZIP option to `true`. Sometimes the video uploaded with `gzip: true` cannot be played. (I couldn't find what it was about)

The problem was fixed when I did `gzip: false` while the video was uploading.

```
        options = {
            destination: key,
            gzip: false,
            public:  true,
        };

        return await bucket.upload(localFilePath, options);
```