# mp4 file sourced from AWS S3 via API Gateway doesn't play on MacOS (Safari)

Tags: macos, http, safari, mp4, api-gateway

I have an S3 integration set up in an API Gateway endpoint and it works well in most cases when uploading/downloading content to/from my S3 bucket. One problem that I have is that I can play mp4 files via my API Gateway in Safari on MacOS.

I followed that post ([<video> plays in other browsers, but not Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27712778/video-plays-in-other-browsers-but-not-safari)) and I learned that default MacOS player requires an http server to allow byte-range responses in order to properly play mp4 files. So what I did is I allowed passing `Range` parameter in request header in API Gateway and, in response, I return `Accept-Ranges: 'bytes'` in header. Additionally API Gateway responds with `206` status which is a proper one for data returned in chunks.

The one thing I spotted is that the request from the web browser goes with `Range: bytes=0-` indicating that the file is requested in one chunk. And, as a result I receive single response with whole file.
On the other hand, when examining request/response with this stock video (https://assets.mixkit.co/videos/preview/mixkit-waves-in-the-water-1164-large.mp4), also sourced from S3 according to what I see in the response header, the requests are separated into chunks and response is provided in pieces as well.

So, is there something I'm missing in API Gateway to make it work?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: Unfortunately not. We changed the approach in the project shortly after we discovered this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found the root cause was the videos were H.265-encoded MP4s but Apple recommends (requires?) H.264-encoded MP4s and mention this in [the "Delivering Video Content for Safari" documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/delivering_video_content_for_safari#overview).

Strangely 1 of my H.265-encoded MP4s did load and play but the other, much larger MP4 did not until I changed to H.264-encoded video.

It seems the devil really is in the details.